# iOS transition animation for pushViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I have an AppDelegate, which owns a window, and from there on, A main view, from which when I go to the next view, I push the new view in order to use the same Navigation Controller and toolbar:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.appview = [[AppointmentView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppointmentView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    @synchronized(self.MahAppntmnts){                             // Set the view's appointment
        [appview setMyAppointment:[[MahAppntmnts MyAppointments] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    }
    [super addChildViewController:self.appview];
    AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [del.navigationController pushViewController:self.appview animated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Now this works fine for switching views, but when I'm trying to go back, I get the same boring flip transition.
I tried setting on my AppView's viewWillDissapear delegate method:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.375];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

This seems to work for when I go back to the previous view, but when I try to transition to new views (using the same method as before) they either not appear, or I flip by to the same view. So I'm guessing that this code should not be on viewWillDissapear, or that I am doing something wrong...

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but it doesn't seem right that you are doing the transition in `viewWillDisappear:`. Can you put that code in a different method that gets called with a button press?

Comment: Well thats the thing, I do not know where to put it for when going back to the previous view. I normally would put it in viewWillDissapear but this seems to break something beyond my comprehension of the issue. Is there like another delegate method such as popView or similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the solution, problem was my miss-conception to "whom" the animation belonged to. I added the code found in viewWillDissapear (located in the pushed view), to the viewWillAppear delegate of the view that did the pushing in the first place (the code found in accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath), so that the controlling view initiates the animation when pushing another view, and when another view navigates back to it, the reverse animation is displayed. Solved all problems and works like a charm.